# spliting a string after the second ":"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get text from a `Get-WinEvent` messageblock, normally I simply use this to get the first sentence:

```
($_.Message).split(".")[0]
```

This works fine if the first part is seperated by a `.`

The Message-Block looks like this:

```
Remotedesktopdienste: Die Sitzungsanmeldung war erfolgreich:

Benutzer: testlab\testuser.local
Sitzungs-ID: 1
Quellnetzwerkadresse: LOKAL.
```

I try to extract only the part `Remotedesktopdienste: Die Sitzungsanmeldung war erfolgreich:` (including the `:` would be perfect, but not mandatory)

Simply using the `:` as delimiter did not work (the second part is missing).

After that, I tried to use

```
($_.Message).split(':',2)[0]
```

Should be the second `:` in the message-block, this gives `Remotedesktopdienste`

Another idea was to use

```
($_.Message).split('[\r\n]',2)[0]
```

to use the second new line, also no success with that, the result is  `Remotedesktopdie`

Comment: something like this should work: ($_.Message).split("`r")[0]

Comment: ... or ``n`. Keep in mind, PowerShell doen't escape using `\``, it uses the backtick ```` Oh crap that code highlighting.... What I want to say: Backslash (Schraegstrich) doesn't work as escape char in PS. Use the backtick (Apostroph or ho you'd call it.)

Comment: Jayvee your solution works, i use `($_.Message).split("`r")[0]` , works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want to split by newline:

```
 $MessageArray = $Message.Split("`n")
```

and then you can iterate through it

```
$Counter = 0
$MessageBody = ""
foreach($Line in $MessageArray) {
     if($Counter -eq 0) {
          $FirstLine = $Line
     } else {
          $MessageBody += $Line + "`n"
     }
     $Counter++
}
```

Result is: `$FirstLine` has your first line .. `$MessageBody` has the rest of the message

**Update**: you can even do it with this onliner

```
 $FirstLine,$MessageBody = $Message.Split("`n")
```